# Matrices $2\times 2$ surfaces of codimension 2.

Tags: matrices, manifolds

I'm reading the book "Int. to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos By Stephen Wiggins" and this book find the following affirmation.

> In the four-dimensional space of $2 \times 2$ real matrices the matrices
> $$\left(\begin{matrix}0&-\omega\\\omega&0 \end{matrix}\right), \hspace{2mm}(\star) $$
> and
> $$\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\0&0 \end{matrix}\right)$$
> lie on surfaces of codimension 2.

But I don't know how prove this affirmation. In first stage I try to identify $M_{2\times2 }\equiv \mathbb{R}^{4}$ and the set of matrices in the form $\star$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and so justify why at least in this case we have codimension 2, but if it work in the other case this not work. It was my attempt but don't work. How can I prove this affirmation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Matrices of type $\star$ form a $1$ dimensional space.  Matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}0&A\\B&0 \end{bmatrix}$ form a two dimensional space.

Comment: Hi @lulu But, I still continue without understanding how prove the stament.

Comment: What is the codimension of the surface I described?

Comment: I think that in the first case, matrices of type $\star$ the codimension is 3, and the other case, $\left(\begin{matrix}0&A\\ B&0\end{matrix}\right)$ is 2. Really I don't sure. I try to idenfy this spaces with $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, k chosee according the case, to give my answer.

Comment: I don't understand.  I described an explicit surface ($A,B$ can be arbitrary real numbers, of course).  And my surface contains all the matrices you wrote down.  Isn't that what you wanted?  If this is missing something, please state clearly what else needs to be constructed or demonstrated.

Comment: Thanks, @lulu  I understand, only I have trouble with the matriz $\star$ since in the first instance you say that form a 1 dimensional space, which is true, but I belived that means that  shen only "live" in a surface of codimension 3, but she also can "live" in surface of codimension 2.

Comment: You can have a curve on a surface.  No contradiction there...

Comment: Your question has a so evident answer... For example, matrices $\left(\begin{matrix}0&-\omega\\\omega&0 \end{matrix}\right)$ constitute a one-dimensional vector space; i.e., a straight line... therefor belongs to a 2D vector space, itself with codimension 2.